# how to insert statics into table in loop with Mysql?

Tags: mysql

for example, I decide a piecewise function

1. when x=1 then y(x)=0,
2. when  1<x<100 then y(x)=(x+3)/5 + y(x-1),  # (x+3)/5 means discard decimals, and y(x-1) means the value of y when x=x-1.  and the function takes integer whole number
3. when x=100    then y(x)=1000

'table' contains two elements (id,val) both in int type.

> ```
> >     delimiter $$ 
> >     drop procedure if exists addTest;
> >     create procedure addTest()
> >     begin
> >     declare i int;
> >     set i = 1;
> >     while i<=100
> >     do
> >     select val as num from table where id=i-1;
> >     
> >     if i=1 then
> >     insert into table values(1,0);
> >     
> >     elseif i>1 and i<100 then
> >     insert into table values(i,(i+3)/5 + num);
> >     
> >     else
> >     insert into table values(100,1000);
> >     
> >     END
> >     if;
> >     
> >     set i = i+1;
> >     
> >     end 
> >     while;
> >     end $$;
> ```

I want to insert these statics (x,y) into a 'table' from x=1 to x=100.

But the code only insert (1,0) into 'table' and it stops.

Comment: if you expand the formula, it is just `min(1000, max(0, (x-1)*(4+x/2))/5)`

Comment: Hello, I post my code above. Could you tell me any mistakes there.

Answer (score 1):

by creating a function:

```
delimiter $$
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;
drop FUNCTION if exists get_parent_list;
create FUNCTION get_parent_list(in_id int) returns int
BEGIN
declare ids int;
declare valx int;

set ids= in_id-1;
select val into valx from table where id=ids;
return valx;
END
$$
```

then use the function in your query.